# A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shared_preferences:createFullJarDebug'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shared_preferences:createFullJarDebug'.

> File 'H:\flutter\info_app\build\shared_preferences\intermediates\runtime_library_classes\debug\classes.jar' specified for property 'libraryInputFile' does not exist.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try using `flutter clean` and then rebuilding the app again

Comment: i used flutter clean still i have the same error. Rebuilding this huge project is very tough. Can you suggest me any other alternatives

Comment: What does `flutter doctor` output?

Comment: When he says rebuilding he means run it again, not re programming it.

Comment: Yes, I mean to compile it and run it in your virtual device

Comment: flutter doctor doesn't show any error.

Comment: If you do not provide more information this is not solvable. Have you trying what I have said?

Comment: Things i have tried --> flutter clean, flutter doctor ( doesn't show any error), updating flutter and then rebuilding again. still no luck. same error!

Comment: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':shared_preferences:createFullJarDebug' <<< this is what i get.

Comment: update:i was using shared preferences to save data now i am using hive to store the data. still can not understand why this error occurred